# Headless browser get data-URI of an image without losing the quality

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-chromedriver, data-uri

I am trying to save a captcha locally with a headless Chrome browser, don't wanna take a screenshot and without losing the quality of the captcha.

The way I came up with is to convert the image to data-URI and then write it to a file.

I try the following code, it did work and save an image for me. The problem is, the captcha I got is not as good as the one I just download or take a screenshot.

```py
captcha_img_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='some text']//img")

img_base64 = browser.execute_script("""
    var ele = arguments[0];
    var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
    cnv.width = ele.width; cnv.height = ele.height;
    cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(ele, 0, 0);
    return cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22);    
    """, captcha_img_element)

with open("captcha_js.png", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_base64))
```

The one with high quality:

[image: high]

The one I got through js code:

[image: low]

they look the same, but when you zoom up them, the pixels are different.

So, how can I get the data-URI of the first one (with high quality), or is there any alternative way without using data-URI (under headless browser mode)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ele.intrinsicWidth` and `ele.intrinsicHeight`. This gives the actual width and height of the image and not the width/height of the DOM element.

Comment: I replaced ```ele.width``` with ```ele.intrinsicWidth```,```ele.height``` with ```ele.intrinsicHeight```, it did not save the image for me. Instead, I try ```ele.naturalWidth``` and it saved the image but with the same quality as using ```ele.width```